# How To Pin RUN.LNK to Taskbar, Verbs are Missing

Tags: powershell, taskbar

I am finding difficulty trying to pin RUN.LNK to my 2012 taskbar.  I've used the various pin examples here and elsewhere, with no luck.  I've tried all the RUN.LNK scattered around the disk without success.

None of these have the Pin or Unpin verbs present.
I'm confused because I can manually pin from the Metro tiles.
I cannot figure out where these are sourced.
Doing the Open File Location from the tile gets me to a RUN.LNK, but it has no verbs for Pinning.

I want to pin RUN, CMD, SERVICES, EVENTS, and a few other daily use icons.
My script gets most of them, but not RUN.LNK.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is creating a new link with an ActiveX object and FileRun() method.  This can be done either with Powershell or JScript.  Testing shows the JScript method is FAR faster, because of the Powershell startup latency.

This code is copy/paste tested in a Powershell 3.0 command window.  For clarity, all error checking, etc is removed.

1) Create a RUN.JS file with contents
'new ActiveXObject("Shell.Application").FileRun();'

2) Create a RUN.LNK pointing to the RUN.JS file.

3) Pin the new link to the Taskbar

```
# -------------
# Create RUN.JS
# -------------
Out-File -Force -FilePath 'c:\windows\run.js' -InputObject 'new ActiveXObject("Shell.Application").FileRun();'


# -----------
# Create Link
# -----------
$objWsh                  = New-Object -ComObject Wscript.Shell
$objLnk                  = $objWsh.CreateShortcut('c:\windows\run.lnk')
$objLnk.Arguments        = 'c:\windows\run.js'
$objLnk.Description      = 'Open RUN Box'
$objLnk.IconLocation     = 'c:\windows\system32\shell32.dll,-25'
$objLnk.TargetPath       = 'c:\windows\system32\wscript.exe'
$objLnk.WorkingDirectory = 'c:\windows\'
$objLnk.Save()


# --------------
# Pin to Taskbar
# --------------
$objShell = New-Object -ComObject Shell.Application
$objItem  = $objShell.Namespace(0).Parsename('c:\windows\run.lnk')
$objVerb  = $objItem.Verbs() | ? { $_.Name -like '*Pin to Tas*' }
$objVerb.Doit()

# -------
# Cleanup
# -------
[Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($objWsh)
[Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($objShell)
```